# Call a specific class method in Java (without polymorphism)

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I'm having a problem in Java. I have a method that can be extended. The problem is, that this method calls other methods of the class, and these can be extended as well.

Consider the following class:

```
public class Foo {
    protected int xLast;

    public updateMe(int x, int y) {
        updateX(x);
    }

    protected updateX(int x) {
        this.xLast = x;
    }
}
```

This class is extended by the following class:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    protected int xAverage = 0;
    protected int xCount = 0;
    protected int y;

    public updateMe(int x, int y) {
        super.updateMe(x, y);       
        updateX(x);
        updateY(x);
    }

    protected updateX(int x) {
        this.xAverage = (this.xAverage * this.xCount) + x;
        this.xCount++;
        this.xAverage /= xCount;
    }

    protected updateY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

And also by this class:

```
public class Abc extends Foo {
}
```

When I do the following:

```
Foo myBar = new Bar();
myBar.updateMe(1, 2);
```

The `Foo.updateX` method is not called, but the `Bar.updateX` method is called twice. There are several solutions, some don't work well or are quite ugly:

1. In `Bar.updateX` call `super.updateX`. This will cause both `updateX` methods to be called twice.
2. Remove the `updateX` call in `Foo.updateMe`, forcing the extending classes to call `super.updateX`. This will cause the class `Abc` to have useless code that it doesn't need, or else the Abc class will not call `updateX` at all.
3. Rename the methods so that they do not override each other. This will work, but is not safe (in the future this might be forgotten and lead to problems) and is not enforced by the language.

I am aware that this is somewhat of a code-smell, but I see no better way to do this.

Basically I am looking to do something like this: in `Foo.updateMe` I would like to call `Foo.updateX` specifically, and not just the polymorph-ed `updateX`.

I believe that something like the `new` method keyword in C# can solve my problems, but Java doesn't appear to have one, or any other way to accomplish this.

**Edit:**

In the end I chose just to rename the offending method. I have a just one method that causes this problem, and the solution suggested here, although sound from a design point-of-view will make this particular code harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: I do not really understand what you want,although you can use IOC(Inversion of control) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Comment: what is the relation of this question with IOC?.. IOC is not silver bullet to end our eternal problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do this:

1. Remove updateX() call from Bar.updateMe() since updateX() is already called by super.updateMe().
2. Call super.updateX() from Bar.updateX() since the method with the same name is supposed to extend functionality, not replace it.

In this case Abc won't have to be changed and both updateX() methods will be called once.

Comment: I like your suggestion, and it is also the most logically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Java , all instance method calls are called by means of dynamic binding. As far as I know, there is no elegant way to accomplish what you want.

If you dont care about principles and elegance, you can check class of an instance at Foo.

```
public updateMe(int x, int y) { 
   if (getClass()==Foo.class)         
        updateX(x);     
}
```

Comment: This is actually a rather fool-proof way to handle this, especially when adding logic to handle all the cases (the extending classes call some of the `super` methods, and not the other, none at all, etc.)

Comment: As I said, there is no elegant and reasonable way.

Answer (score 1):

Eli, it seems that you would like to cancel OOP. First it is bad. If you need this change your design. Java is pure object oriented language and therefore all calls are polymorphic. If you extended your class and overrode some if its functionality it means that you need this and therefore this functionality should be called. This is the reason that `updateX()` from `Bar` is called.

BTW to do what you want you should create static method and call it this way: Foo.updateX().

Comment: I am aware that this is not classic OOP. In the `updateX` I must have access to non-static members, so can't make it a static method.

Comment: Generally, access to non-static methods is not a problem - you could pass instance as a parameter of static method, and access fields of instance.

Comment: @Kel Yes, but I think it a rather ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make updateX() private.  Then a subclass that implements updateX() is "hiding", not "overriding" the method.

Drawbacks:
Since updateX() is conceptually part of a Template pattern, it really "feels" like it should be protected.

You can't put
`abstract private void updateX();` 
in the superclass to force users to implement it.

All implementations of updateMe() must always remember to call updateX()

Possible Drawback and possible advantage:

All of the private updateMe() methods will get called.  (for me this this was desired, YMMV)

I recently faced this problem and chose this solution, though I considered renaming the methods and something very close to the (getClass()== MyFoo.class) trick.  IMO all are reasonable.